# Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid OpenIdConnect SignOutAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I get an error

> Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be
>   missing or invalid when signing out.

when I handle signing out

```
public async Task LogOut()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);            
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
}
```

**Schemas**

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Access/Unauthorised");
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["oidc:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["oidc:ClientSecret"]; // for code flow
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["oidc:SignedOutRedirectUri"];
        options.Authority = Configuration["oidc:Authority"];
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oidc");
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("pfidpadapterid", Configuration["oidc:PingProtocolMessage"]);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like your authorization server does not support Session Management and Dynamic Registration. When it's supported, the discovery response contains `end_session_endpoint`. This is not the same as [SignedOutRedirectUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.signedoutredirecturi?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which is used as a final redirection target when the user is logged out on authorization server.

`OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut` event provides an option to set the issuer address, which in this case is the logout URI:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress =
            GetAbsoluteUri(Configuration["oidc:EndSessionEndpoint"], Configuration["oidc:Authority"]);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
}
```

The helper method is used to support both relative and absolute path in the configuration:

```
private string GetAbsoluteUri(string signoutUri, string authority)
{
    var signOutUri = new Uri(signoutUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    var authorityUri = new Uri(authority, UriKind.Absolute);

    var uri = signOutUri.IsAbsoluteUri ? signOutUri : new Uri(authorityUri, signOutUri);
    return uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

This way the authorization server will [get additional parameters](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RedirectionAfterLogout) in the query string, which it can use e.g. to redirect back to your application.

Comment: What is the `IssuerAddress` and which exactly address should I put there?

Comment: @Monsignor You must put a remote sign-out URL for your IdP sign-out purpose.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this handle the **[`OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut`](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-mvc-samples/blob/master/Quickstart/01-Login/SampleMvcApp/Startup.cs)** event and specify the Logout endpoint manually:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("pfidpadapterid", Configuration["oidc:PingProtocolMessage"]);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
    // handle the logout redirection 
    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
    {
        var logoutUri = Configuration["oidc:SignedOutRedirectUri"];
        context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```