# ASP.NET Core MVC - Logout from external provider with POST request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, openid-connect

Basic problem:
I have an APS.NET Core web-app using EKOAPP as external authentication provider with OpenIdConnect. I want my users to be able to logout when they have finished their work, but apparently EKOAPP does not implement the session management standard.

Basically, from what I found out so far, the only way to actually logout a user from EKOAPP is to do a POST request to https://app-h1.eu.ekoapp.com/api/v1/auth/logout whereby the user is identified with some sort of session cookie. So, just sending a post request with HttpClient or similar won't do, as that cookie is not available in the backend (as it comes from an external url). Meaning that some sort of redirect is kind of inevitable (as far as I think I understood).

First off, the basic attempt of just trying:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    // with or without return Redirect("/Home/Index");
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    return new SignOutResult(new[] { 
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme 
    });
}
```

just triggers "Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid when signing out." => see [Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid OpenIdConnect SignOutAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815961/cannot-redirect-to-the-end-session-endpoint-the-configuration-may-be-missing-or)

Trying to implement the solution from there, does frankly, nothing at all. As far as I can tell from browser network logging, it doesn't even bother to try calling the logout url.

One thing that does work for logging out is:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return RedirectPreserveMethod("https://app-h1.eu.ekoapp.com/api/v1/auth/logout");
}
```

**Edit-Start**
Actually, it only seemed to work, as it showed the login screen again - however the user is not actually getting logged out. Guess I'll have to abandon this...
**Edit-End**

However, the user then ends up at the login screen of EKOAPP and, when actually logging in, stays at EKOAPP instead of getting returned to my app.

I also tried a frontend centered approach:

```
$("#logout").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://app-h1.eu.ekoapp.com/api/v1/auth/logout",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: !0
        },
        headers: {
            ajax: !0
        },
        method: "post"
    }).done(function () {
        location = "/Home/Index";
    });
})
```

Unfortunately, that just triggers a Cross Origin Request exception ...

Any ideas? Is that even possible what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As you've already deduced, you'll need to use a browser-based approach, and AJAX won't work. If you dig into the various implementations of OpenID-Connect you'll see that it includes a lot of redirects to work around the same kinds of limitations.

One possible solution is to include the following in your logout process:

- Redirect to a page that includes a form that posts to your provider's logout endpoint.
- Use JavaScript to automatically post the form (you should also include a button to post the form in case JavaScript fails for some reason).
- Your authentication provider should have configuration for the logout redirect location, and posting to their logout endpoint should redirect to that location. You can use that to return to your home page.

Comment: Well, EkoApp only offers one redirect-url that one can configure, which I kind of have to set to https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc to make the sign-in work.
But anyhow, the point would be to actually get the user to the logout, which won't work on a simple "post to external url", as the browser does not attach the appropriate cookies, meaning EkoApp does not identify the user

Comment: The logout URL should receive the cookies set by the login unless they were set for a different domain, in which case I would question if that's the correct logout URL. I work with an in-house identity system based on IdentityServer4 and the way I described above is how logout works in that system. One final note: I'm assuming you're talking about a logout process that is initiated by the logged in user in the same browser where they are logged in.

Comment: The login seems to not mind whether it was initiated by our app or by the user actually having used EkoApp before navigating to our app. As far as I understand:
1.) user navigates to our app
2.) ASP redirects user to EkoApp login page
3.) User logs in (cookie is set in the EkoApp domain, not ours)
4.) EkoApp redirects user to the defined redirect url (localhost/signin-oidc)
5.) User can use our app, but apparently there is no way to logout the user...