# ASP.NET Core MVC OpenIdConnect how do I check if HttpContext.SignOutAsync is allowed?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using OpenIdConnect with Auth0 (via the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package) and the call to `HttpContext.SignOutAsync(..)` fails with an error

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid.

This is expected because Auth0's well known configuration does not publish a signout endpoint (which is a bit funky given how hard they push their book on OAuth).

I'm trying to figure out how, if at all, I can get the current OpenIdConnect configuration settings that were loaded from the well known endpoint. I'd like to check for myself if the signout endpoint exists instead of eating the exception.

Plus from a logging/debugging/supporting a raft of other providers I really would like to get the well known settings currently loaded. For example I'm expecting at some point to have to support Broadcom's SiteMinder... which if past experience has taught me anything is going to involve sufficient logging such that I can pass the problem over to my client's technical folks (to either fix or take up with SiteMinder people).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most standard option is for the OpenID Connect metadata to include an `end_session_endpoint`. When that is missing you will get the above .NET error by default.

[RP Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) is a draft specification, and some providers have custom implementations. [This post](https://community.auth0.com/t/conform-to-openid-logout-specification/82498) discusses Auth0's behaviour, and you will need to build a custom logout URL.

In .NET you can use [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to resolve your issues, and you will need code similar to the following - from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815961/cannot-redirect-to-the-end-session-endpoint-the-configuration-may-be-missing-or).

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
  Authority = ...
  ClientId = ...
  Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
  {
    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
    {
      context.IssuerAddress = myAuth0CustomLogoutUrl;
    }
  }
});
```

The above context also has an [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0) object that you can use to get the metadata, via its `ConfigurationManager` property.

Alternatively you can get metadata like this outside of event handlers. This will allow you to detect if the downloaded metadata contains an end session endpoint.

```cs
var url = $"{authorityUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(url, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(config.EndSessionEndpoint))
{
  // Do something
}
```

A more elegant option might be to register the OpenIdConnectOptions object as a singleton, then inject it into the logout controller. You can then access the exact ConfigurationManager instance that the infrastructure is using:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(options);

class LogoutController
{
  public LogoutController(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
  {
  }

  public SomeMethod()
  {
    // Use options
  }
}
```

You can put any custom logging either in the above handler or in `OnMessageReceived`, which will also fire whenever an OIDC message is received - eg metadata is downloaded.

Comment: I was aware of the event based approach but I could need to drop the settings into cache so that they would be available on the logout page. I'd really rather be able to get the settings that the infrastructure is using. They're have the authoritative settings, and I'd rather rely on them (if you see what I mean). Thanks though.

Comment: Ok - I updated the answer above - see if these suggestions help